# Parsing JSON array to label

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dispatch

I am trying to parse the JSON below (actual data is 20x the format listed)

```
{
message = "";
result =     (
            {
        Ask = "4.8e-05";
        BaseVolume = "32.61025363";
        Bid = "4.695e-05";
        Created = "2017-06-06T01:22:35.727";
        High = "5.44e-05";
        Last = "4.69e-05";
        Low = "4.683e-05";
        MarketName = "BTC-1ST";
        OpenBuyOrders = 293;
        OpenSellOrders = 4186;
        PrevDay = "4.76e-05";
        TimeStamp = "2018-02-20T00:00:31.863";
        Volume = "662575.93818332";
    },
```

This is the code that I have right now. It successfully prints the value "Last" to the console but when I incorporate the Dispatch.Queue, I get a `Thread 1: signal SIGBRT` not printing the value to the label.

```
let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as! [String:Any]

if let info = myJson["result"] as! [[String:Any]]?
{
    for i in 0..<20 {
        if i == 1
        {
            if let dict = info[i] as? [String:Any]
            {
                if let price = dict["Last"]
                {
                    print(price)
                    //DispatchQueue.main.async
                    //{
                    //   self.label1.text =  price as String
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your `self.label1` outlet isn't connected. Fix that connection.

You should also update the `if let` that gets the value for the `"Last"` key as follows:

```
if let price = dict["Last"] as? String{
    print(price)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.label1.text =  price
    }
}
```

There is some other cleanup you can do as well:

```
if let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as? [String:Any] {
    if let info = myJson["result"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        for (index, dict) in info.enumerated() {
            if index == 1 {
                if let price = dict["Last"] as? String {
                    print(price)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.label1.text =  price
                    }
                } // else no "Last" or not a String
            }
        }
    } // else "result" doesn't contain expected array of dictionary        
} // else content isn't a valid JSON dictionary
```

Avoid all of those forced casts. Especially avoid force casting to an optional.

Comment: First off, thank you for your help. I have the label connected via `@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!` and have updated to your code but it is still not displaying. The price is also not outputting to the console either. Do you have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: How far does the code get? Also note that indexes start at 0 so maybe you want `index == 0`.

Comment: It's also quite likely that `price` isn't actually a `String`. It is probably a number. Try changing `as? String` to `as? NSNumber`. Then change ` = price` to ` = price.stringValue`.

Comment: That did it! I've been looking at this code all day so thank you.

Answer (score -1):

JSON doesn't use the `=` sign or the semicolon. Change every `=` to a colon and every semicolon to a comma, so that

```
    Ask = "4.8e-05";
    BaseVolume = "32.61025363";
    Bid = "4.695e-05";
```

Becomes

```
    Ask: "4.8e-05",
    BaseVolume: "32.61025363",
    Bid: "4.695e-05",
```

Comment: I can't edit the actual json unfortunately. I found a way to work with the = signs in another code though.

Comment: Since OP's code works for the most part, clearly the issue is not with the format of the JSON. The "JSON" shown is actually the output of logging the parsed dictionary so there is nothing to fix in regard to the JSON.